# Plugin React was cnonflicted between package.json

Tags: reactjs, plugins, eslint

Any project I create using

`npx create-react-app`

When compiling the project, the same message always appears:

`Plugin react'' was conflicted between package.json eslint-config-react-app and BaseConfig`

I've tried deleting and reinstalling eslint, but to no avail.

The only alternative so far was to Ctrl + S all the time on the `package.json` file to compile it again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the cause of the problem for me was that when I cd'ed into my project's directory, I wrote the folder names in lower case, while the actual folders were named in sentence case.

So make sure that the path you cd into from the terminal has the same exact capitalization as the real path. Doing that fixed the problem for me.